# WordCram How to get word frequency

Tags: java

[WordCram](http://wordcram.org/) is a java based tool to produce Word Clouds. It eliminate the stop words and then uses word frequencies to decide on font size of the Word in the picture.

Is it possible to output this word, word frequency into a text file?

Comment: Could you expound on your question and possibly add some code that you have attempted with the text file?  Currently as it stands the answer to your question is a simple "Yes" or "No"

Comment: I've never heard of it, but browsing the javadoc for 2 minutes allows finding the getWords() method, returning an array of Words, each having a String word and a weight. http://danbernier.github.io/WordCram/javadoc/wordcram/WordCram.html#getWords%28%29

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is just a yes/no question about  library.